# How to move to previous Row in DataGridView using Button Click

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have the following problem. I have a datagridview and would like to use a button press to go to the previous row based on the selected row. means line 10 is selected and when the button is clicked it should select line 9.

From Row 0 to the last row works. When i select an other row (row 10 or whatever) and press the button nothing happend.
I hope you can help me.

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int number_of_rows;
    private int selected_row;

    private void Button_previous_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number_of_rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; // Rowcount
        if (number_of_rows > 0)
        {
            selected_row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            if (selected_row > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = false;
                selected_row = selected_row--;
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = false;
                selected_row = number_of_rows - 1;                    
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = true;
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Although I don't know for sure this sounds promising: [SetSelectedRowCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.setselectedrowcore?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Thx. But this is not the Problem. I have a readonly Error.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle moving row to row in a DataGridView is by using a BindingSource and BindingNavigator. Set the DataSource property of the data to view in the DataGridView to the BindingSource, add a BindingNavigator and set the DataSource property to the BindingSource.

The following screenshot has a BindingNavigator at the top. See the [following project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/tree/master/DataGridViewCombo), specifically [these lines](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/q-a-questions/blob/master/DataGridViewCombo/MainForm.cs#L46:L47) to get an idea how to implement.

[image]

Also note, without a BindingNavigator you can use methods of the BindingSource e.g. MoveNext for instance to change the selected DataGridView row.

Comment: Thanks very much. I solved the problem before reading your answer. I'll post the code as an answer.

Comment: Saw your solution, in general its better to learn how to work with a BindingNavigator or a BindingNavigator/BindingSource which means no math.

Comment: @MarkusFiedler do not post solutions as edits to questions; post them as answers in their own right. Nothing prevents you from answering your own question. Karen's approach is the one I'd take

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I will inform myself about the use of BindingNavigator/BindingSource. Thanks for the hints =)
I have solved it as follows for now.

```
number_of_rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; // Rowcount
        if (number_of_rows > 0)
        {
            selected_row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            if (selected_row > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = false;                    
                selected_row = --selected_row;                    
                dataGridView1.Rows[selected_row].Selected = true;                    
            }
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. IMHO, documenting the adopted approach in the original post as an edit, below the original question, better serves the StackOverflow community.